# Should I use Internals::SvREADONLY for creating readonly variables in Perl?

Tags: perl, readonly, scalar

Looking into the [Const::Fast source](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LEONT/Const-Fast-0.006/lib/Const/Fast.pm) I noticed that it used the built-in function `Internals::SvREADONLY` internally. Is it safe to use that function directly in my Perl script? It seems to be present in core from Perl 5.8.

```
my $PI = 4 * atan2 1, 1;
Internals::SvREADONLY($PI => 1);
$PI = 2.718;   # Modification of a read-only value attempted at ..
```

Comment: Why use it directly when there are libraries that do it for you, while taking care of the edge cases and caveats?

Comment: Yeah, Attribute::Constant's Data::Lock is basically the same as Const::Fast, so use either of those.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
C:\>perldoc Internals
No documentation found for "Internals".
```

No.

More specifically, the package is named "Internals" for a reason. It is not intended for use outside the core. It could change without notice.

Comment: By implication, one should then not use either [Const::Fast](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Const%3A%3AFast) or [Readonly](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Readonly)? They both use `Internals::SvREADONLY`...

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch: That's something you need to decide for yourself based on your needs and risk-tolerance. In general, you aren't expected to know anything about how a module is implemented. Code you write can use any modules you choose but should not violate their interface or encapsulation. The authors of those modules have assumed the risk of their code being broken by changes in future versions of perl.

Answer (score 3):

This is not quite answering your question, but I think it is worth mentioning so others don't experience the same pain as I have: don't use *any* readonly value if you're running on a version of Perl earlier than 5.10.1.  Consider this little example:

```
{
    package Foo;
    sub foo { print "I'm in foo!\n"; }
}

use strict;
use warnings;
use Readonly;
Readonly my @classes => qw(Foo);

foreach my $class (@classes)
{
    # this dies with "Can't call method "foo" without a package or object reference"
    $class->foo;
}
```

Since my XS-fu is not very high, I can't explain what is going on here very coherently (but Devel::Peek shows some interesting things in the `$class` variable).

Comment: Do you have `Readonly::XS` installed? I know that `Const::Fast` was created because `Readonly` could be very flaky.

Comment: @Ven: yes, this is with Readonly::XS, and the same issue occurs with Const::Fast. The issue is that method resolution does not work properly on SvReadonly scalars pre 5.10.x.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu: Readonly::XS is not used in sub Readonly (only in sub Readonly::Scalar), this is a long standing bug that Eric Roode refuses to fix.