# Restricted hashes update not atomic only with `lock_keys` not `lock_hash`

Tags: perl

Tested with Perl 5.24 on OS X

I'm trying to figure out why attempting to update a restricted hash clears the hash table (violating atomicity) only when the *keys* of the hash are restricted. If `lock_hash` has been applied to the hash, then the illegal modification is completely rolled back.

The documentation for `Hash::Util` claims, in part.

> CAVEATS
>
> Note that the trapping of the restricted operations is not
>   atomic: for example
>
> eval { %hash = (illegal_key => 1) }
>
> leaves the %hash empty rather than with its original contents.

I originally wanted to see whether individual operations like updating a single illegal key were atomic and whether Perl 5.24 would emit a warning in this situation, but when I first tried I couldn't reproduce the behavior.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Hash::Util qw[lock_hash lock_keys];
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (a => 1, b => 2);
lock_hash(%hash);

eval { %hash = (illegal_key => 1) };

print Dumper \%hash;
```

This prints

```
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => 1,
          'b' => 2
        };
```

Using, `lock_keys`, however, does reproduce the behavior

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings FATAL => 'all';
use Hash::Util qw[lock_hash lock_keys];
use Data::Dumper;

my %hash = (a => 1, b => 2);
lock_keys(%hash);

eval { %hash = (illegal_key => 1) };

print Dumper \%hash;
```

prints an empty hashref, as the documentation foretold

```
$VAR1 = {};
```

Why is there a difference in behavior depending on how the hash is restricted?

Comment: You're making it sound like you are sure it's related to the Perl version. The behavior is from the module Hash::Util though. Start by reading its code. It's probably related to internals of Perl but I doubt that something changed in 5.24 specifically in this regard.

Comment: @simbabque I'm not confident that it's related to the Perl version, but I haven't tested the code snippets with other Perl versions or on other platforms. I'm not sure what the right way is to communicate that information.

Comment: You just did. :-) the second time you said 5.24 implied you were sure. I'll test it on different versions in a bit, I'm on a phone right now. Look at http://perlbrew.pl for installing multiple different Perls if you care to try yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried two different versions of Perl 5.10.1 and 5.18.2 and the behavior was the same as yours and probably there are some limitation when using old versions of Perl.

There is a slightly difference between lock_hash and lock_key.

When you call lock_hash it does:

```
lock_keys(%$hash);

foreach my $key (keys %$hash) {
    lock_value(%$hash, $key);
}
```

So it locks the keys of your hash and the values while lock_keys:

```
Internals::hv_clear_placeholders %$hash;
if( @keys ) {
    my %keys = map { ($_ => 1) } @keys;
    my %original_keys = map { ($_ => 1) } keys %$hash;
    foreach my $k (keys %original_keys) {
        die sprintf "Hash has key '$k' which is not in the new key ".
                    "set at %s line %d\n", (caller)[1,2]
          unless $keys{$k};
    }

    foreach my $k (@keys) {
        $hash->{$k} = undef unless exists $hash->{$k};
    }
    Internals::SvREADONLY %$hash, 1;

    foreach my $k (@keys) {
        delete $hash->{$k} unless $original_keys{$k};
    }
}
else {
    Internals::SvREADONLY %$hash, 1;
}
```

I am supposing this is a bug, since you locked the keys but not the hash and then it returns an empty hash when you try to modify.

However some people have already experienced something similar like you in this question:

[Should I use Internals::SvREADONLY for creating readonly variables in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4098816/should-i-use-internalssvreadonly-for-creating-readonly-variables-in-perl)

There are other ways of doing what you want like using TIE or Readonly for example.

Also a piece of documentation about internals here if you want to have a look:

[Internals Documentation](http://search.cpan.org/dist/perl-5.25.6/lib/Internals.pod)

Unfortunately this practice is discouraged :

> SvREADONLY(THING, [, $value])
>
> Set or get whether a variable is readonly or not. Exactly what the readonly flag means depend on the type of the variable affected and the version of perl used.
>
> You are strongly discouraged from using this function directly. It is used by various core modules, like Hash::Util, and the constant pragma to implement higher-level behavior which should be used instead.
>
> See the core implementation for the exact meaning of the readonly flag for each internal variable type.